# How can I rewrite .NET 4.7.2 type to .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to add a mapping part to a .NET 2.0 C# WinForms application.
How can I rewrite the following:

```
public (bool success, string errMsg) FileOpenHandler(string fileName, string layerName , bool reproject)
{
    ...
    return (success, errMsg);
}
```

```
var result = _mapLayersHandler.FileOpenHandler(fileName);
```

Should I create a static class for this type (success, errMsg) ?

Comment: A static class? You can't return a static class so that wouldn't work.

Comment: The alternative to a *tuple* is a small class or struct with the fields/properties of the tuple members.

Comment: You are aware that support for .NET 2.0 ended 12 years ago? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

Comment: I created like this: public static class MapLayersHandlerResult
    {
        private static bool _success = false;
        public static bool success
        {
            get { return _success; }
            set
            {
                _success = value;
            }
        }
        private static string _errMsg = "";
        public static string errMsg
        {
            get { return _errMsg; }
            set
            {
                _errMsg = value;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @KlausGütter I know, but the project has crystal reports (VS2005) in the app and I'm afraid that if I upgrade above .NET FW 3.5 will not work or I wont be able to modify it

Comment: What error are you getting?  Net 4.7.2 has enhancements that may not be available in Net 2 or Net 3.5.  Old code probably has Active X components and you may need to add these components to your machine.